# Properly Escaping Double Quotes in a Javascript Regular Expression Range

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I modify my Javascript Regular expression to return the string: """Collawan Annals of Plastic Surger Jan 1999 vol 42 pg 21 26."""?

How do I properly escape a double quote in a regexp range?

(attempt in Firebug):

```
>>> var input="Collawn \"Annals of Plastic Surgery\" Jan 1999 vol 42 pg 21 26"
>>> input.replace(/[\.,:\[\]-]/g, ' ');
"Collawn "Annals of Plastic Surgery" Jan 1999 vol 42 pg 21 26"
>>> input.replace(/[\.,:\[\]-\"]/g, ' ');
SyntaxError: invalid range in character class { message="invalid range in character class", more...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `"` but the `-` - if you want it to mean a literal dash, you need to put it at the start or the end of the character class:

```
input.replace(/[.,:\[\]"-]/g, ' ');
```

Otherwise `A-Z` means "any character from A to Z", and your regex contained the equivalent of `Z-A` which is an invalid range (`[-"` would be ASCII 91 to 34).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `\]-\"` describes a character range from `]` (U+005D) to `"` (U+0022) that is an illegal range as *start* > *end*.

Escape the `-` too or put it at the start or end of the character class:

```
/[\.,:\[\]\-\"]/g
```

By the way, you only need to escape `]`, and `\`, and, depending on the position, also `-` and `^` inside a character class, so:

```
/[.,:[\]\-"]/g
```